# How to use a lasso with the Vars package?

Tags: r, lasso-regression, covariance-matrix, vector-auto-regression

I'm trying to analyze a high dimensional data set (31 variables, 1100 observations) through a penalized vector autoregression.

Since I'm using the techniques introduced by Diebold et. al (2019) to build a network of connectedness through variance decomposition matrices, I would like to use their package in R:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/vars/versions/1.5-3/topics/fevd

However, this package can only be used with a regular VAR estimate. I would like to use a penalized regression, such a **LASSO**. So, how can I use their package in R, with a penalized VAR?

What did I try?
The `lassovar` package on GitHub; however, I can't use it in the `fevd()` function. It says:

> "only uses estimate from the Vars class."

Comment: You will have to write a custom FEVD function for Lassovars. Can you provide a link to the Lassovars pacakge? I don't see any source code online anywhere.

Comment: @Manfretto did the below answer your question?

Comment: @shadowtalker Hi shadowtalker, unfortunately I'm still having trouble computing the Connectedness Table with a penalized regression. Do you maybe have a clue how to solve it? I would like to comute a connectedness table, like this one: https://ibb.co/JHd2Qmy. This can be computed by the R package, genFEVD() https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/frequencyConnectedness/versions/0.1.6/topics/genFEVD. However, it is not possible to use a penalty term to estimate the VAR(p) model. It only allows for a regular VAR(p) estimation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Providing a candidate solution to this very interesting problem using example data below. To fit the penalised VAR I've used the recently released [BigVAR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BigVAR/BigVAR.pdf) package. At this point it doesn't come with the usual extra functionality of producing FEVDs, historical decomps, prediction fancharts etc., but all the necessary output from the reduced-form model can be obtained through `cv.BigVAR`. This is what I've done as a first step below. I'll leave it to yourself to finetune the reduced-form estimation using the package functionality.

```
# BigVAR ----
library(BigVAR)
library(expm)
library(data.table)

# Create model
data(Y)

p = 4 # lags
k = ncol(Y) # number of equations
N = nrow(Y) - p # number of obs

# Create a Basic VAR-L (Lasso Penalty) with maximum lag order p=4, 10 gridpoints with lambda optimized according to rolling validation of 1-step ahead MSFE
mod1 = constructModel(Y,p,"Basic",gran=c(150,10),RVAR=FALSE,h=1,cv="Rolling",MN=FALSE,verbose=FALSE,IC=TRUE)
results = cv.BigVAR(mod1)

# Get model estimates
A = results@betaPred[,2:ncol(results@betaPred)] # (k x (k*p)) = (3 x (3*4)) coefficient matrix (reduced form)
Sigma = crossprod(resid(varres))/(N-(k*p)-1)
```

From there we can use standard formulas to compute the FEVDs. For an accessible introduction I would highly recommend [Chapter 4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uomcMEioQvILvlM1JZunH5wGmBiu0cIa/view) of 'Structural Vector Autoregressive Analysis' by Lutz Kilian and Helmut Lütkepohl. The below implements everything we need from reduced-form IRFs to the MSPE and finally our formula to compute the FEVD in R. This will may be a lot to take in and I haven't had time to polish this code so this may well be done more efficiently, but hopefully it's still informative. Note that I am using a standard Choleski decomposition to identify the VAR so the usual implications of the ordering of the variables apply.

```
# A number of helper functions ----
# Compute reduced-form IRFs:
compute_Phi = function(p, k, A_comp, n.ahead) {
  
  J = matrix(0,nrow=k,ncol=k*p)
  diag(J) = 1
  
  Phi = lapply(1:n.ahead, function(i) {
    J %*% (A_comp %^% (i-1)) %*% t(J)
  })
  
  return(Phi)
  
}

# Compute orthogonalized IRFs:
compute_theta_kj_sq = function(Theta, n.ahead) {
  
  theta_kj_sq = lapply(1:n.ahead, function(h) { # loop over h time periods
    out = sapply(1:ncol(Theta[[h]]), function(k) {
      terms_to_sum = lapply(1:h, function(i) {
        Theta[[i]][k,]**2
      })
      theta_kj_sq_h = Reduce(`+`, terms_to_sum)
    })
    colnames(out) = colnames(Theta[[h]])
    return(out)
  })
  
  return(theta_kj_sq)
}

# Compute mean squared prediction error:
compute_mspe = function(Theta, n.ahead=10) {
  mspe = lapply(1:n.ahead, function(h) {
    terms_to_sum = lapply(1:h, function(i) {
      tcrossprod(Theta[[i]])
    })
    mspe_h = Reduce(`+`, terms_to_sum)
  })
}

# Function for FEVD:
fevd = function(A, Sigma, n.ahead) {
  
  k = dim(A)[1] # number of equations
  p = dim(A)[2]/k # number of lags
  
  # Turn into companion form:
  if (p>1) {
    A_comp = VarptoVar1MC(A,p,k) 
  } else {
    A_comp = A
  }
  
  # Compute MSPE: ----
  Phi = compute_Phi(p,k,A_comp,n.ahead)
  P = t(chol.default(Sigma)) # lower triangular Cholesky factor
  B_0 = solve(P) # identification matrix
  Theta = lapply(1:length(Phi), function(i) {
    Phi[[i]] %*% solve(B_0)
  })
  theta_kj_sq = compute_theta_kj_sq(Theta, n.ahead) # Squared orthogonaliyed IRFs
  mspe = compute_mspe(Theta, n.ahead)
  
  # Compute percentage contributions (i.e. FEVDs): ----
  fevd_list = lapply(1:k, function(k) {
    t(sapply(1:length(mspe), function(h) {
      mspe_k = mspe[[h]][k,k]
      theta_k_sq = theta_kj_sq[[h]][,k]
      fevd = theta_k_sq/mspe_k
    }))
  })
  
  # Tidy up
  fevd_tidy = data.table::rbindlist(
    lapply(1:length(fevd_list), function(k) {
      fevd_k = data.table::melt(data.table::data.table(fevd_list[[k]])[,h:=.I], id.vars = "h", variable.name = "j")
      fevd_k[,k:=paste0("V",k)]
      data.table::setcolorder(fevd_k, c("k", "j", "h"))
    })
  )
  
  return(fevd_tidy)
}
```

Lastly, lets implement the formula for `n.ahead=20` and plot the results.

```
fevd_res = fevd(A, Sigma, 20)

library(ggplot2)

p = ggplot(data=fevd_res) +
  geom_area(aes(x=h, y=value, fill=j)) +
  facet_wrap(k ~ .) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    expand=c(0,0)
  ) +
  scale_fill_discrete(
    name = "Shock"
  ) +
  labs(
    y = "Variance contribution",
    x = "Forecast horizon"
  ) +
  theme_bw()
p
```

[image: FEVD plots]

Hope this is helpful and please shout if any follow-up questions.

Finally a note of caution: I have tested the FEVD function by comparing it to the results for a standard VAR using the [vars](http://ftp.uni-bayreuth.de/math/statlib/R/CRAN/doc/vignettes/vars/vars.pdf) package that you mention in your question and it checks out (see below). But this is as far as my "unit-testing" has gone. The code has not been reviewed by anyone so just be aware of that and perhaps dig through the formulas yourself. If you or anyone else spots any errors, I'd be grateful for feedback.

**Edit 1**

For the sake of completeness adding a quick comparison of results returned by `vars::fevd` and the custom function from above.

```
# Compare to vars package ----
library(vars)

p = 4 # lags
k = ncol(Y) # number of equations
N = nrow(Y) - p
colnames(Y) = sprintf("V%i", 1:ncol(Y))
n.ahead = 20

varres = vars::VAR(Y,p) # reduced-form model using package command; vars:: to make clear that pkg

# Get estimates for custom fevd function:
Sigma = crossprod(resid(varres))/(N-(k*p)-1)
A = t(
  sapply(coef(varres), function(i) {
    i[,1]
  })
)
A = A[,1:(ncol(A)-1)]

# Run the two different functions:
fevd_pkg = vars::fevd(varres, n.ahead)
fevd_cus = fevd(A, Sigma, n.ahead)
```

Now comparing the outputs for the first variable:

```
> # Package:
> head(fevd_pkg$V1)
            V1         V2         V3
[1,] 1.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
[2,] 0.9399842 0.01303013 0.04698572
[3,] 0.9422918 0.01062750 0.04708065
[4,] 0.9231440 0.01409313 0.06276291
[5,] 0.9305901 0.01335727 0.05605267
[6,] 0.9093144 0.01278727 0.07789833
> # Custom:
> head(dcast(fevd_cus[k=="V1"], k+h~j, value.var = "value"))
    k h        V1         V2         V3
1: V1 1 1.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
2: V1 2 0.9399842 0.01303013 0.04698572
3: V1 3 0.9422918 0.01062750 0.04708065
4: V1 4 0.9231440 0.01409313 0.06276291
5: V1 5 0.9305901 0.01335727 0.05605267
6: V1 6 0.9093144 0.01278727 0.07789833
```

**Edit 2**

To get the generalized FEVD in R without depending on output from `vars::VAR()`, you can use the function below. I have recycled some of the source code of `frequencyConnectedness::genFEVD`.

```
# Generalized FEVD ----
library(frequencyConnectedness)

genFEVD_cus = function(
  A, 
  Sigma, 
  n.ahead, 
  no.corr=F
) {
  
  k = dim(A)[1] # number of equations
  p = dim(A)[2]/k # number of lags
  
  # Turn into companion form:
  if (p>1) {
    A_comp = BigVAR::VarptoVar1MC(A,p,k) 
  } else {
    A_comp = A
  }
  
  # Set off-diagonals to zero:
  if (no.corr) {
    Sigma = diag(diag(Sigma))
  }
  
  Phi = compute_Phi(p,k,A_comp,n.ahead+1) # Reduced-form irfs
  
  denom = diag(Reduce("+", lapply(Phi, function(i) i %*% Sigma %*% 
                                    t(i))))
  enum = Reduce("+", lapply(Phi, function(i) (i %*% Sigma)^2))
  tab = sapply(1:nrow(enum), function(j) enum[j, ]/(denom[j] * 
                                                      diag(Sigma)))
  tab = t(apply(tab, 2, function(i) i/sum(i)))
  
  return(tab)
}
```

Continuing from the above example (**Edit 1**) compare the results from the custom function to results from `frequencyConnectedness::genFEVD` which depends on the output from `vars::VAR()`:

```
> frequencyConnectedness::genFEVD(varres, n.ahead)
             V1         V2         V3
[1,] 0.89215734 0.02281892 0.08502374
[2,] 0.72025050 0.19335481 0.08639469
[3,] 0.08328267 0.11769438 0.79902295
> genFEVD_cus(A, Sigma, n.ahead)
             V1         V2         V3
[1,] 0.89215734 0.02281892 0.08502374
[2,] 0.72025050 0.19335481 0.08639469
[3,] 0.08328267 0.11769438 0.79902295
```

Comment: Het Patalt, sincerely appreciate your answer and the code works perfectly! However, in the function: genFEVD(Var_Normal, n.ahead = 20, no.corr = F). I end up with a 31 x 31 Matrix (31 variables in my model) and all rows add up to 1. When I use your code it only has 6 rows (even though I still have 31 variables), just like in your example. So my question is, how can I calculate the generalized matrix with those n.ahead, lambda estimates, from the big.var package? I think I'm close with your input, but not there yet.

Comment: @Manfretto you'll see above that in my example the column entries add up to one. That reflects the fact that in each row the total variance is decomposed into the contributions of all variables in the system. The number of rows in my example is not 6, but `n.ahead` (so the number of forecast periods). Sorry if I'm stating the obvious, but perhaps you get 6 rows because you still wrap the outputs in `head()`? I'm haven't used `genFEVD` in the past, but I wouldn't expect a square matrix as an output of a forecast error variance decomposition unless the number of variables equals `n.ahead`.

Comment: To be clear, my custom function `fevd_cus` returns the results in tidy format, but you can verify that the variance for each variable `k` at each forecast horizon `h` adds up to one. Also visible from the charts provided. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, appreciated! I totally understand your comments and the output I get is indeed the n.ahead forecast per variable, which is decomposed into contributions of all variables and adds up to 1. However, in the genFEVD() you get a square matrix, just as mentioned in Diebold et al. (2017), where each row adds up to 1 and each cell represents the n.ahead forecast to that particular variable. Here you see an example of my regular VAR estimate with genFEVD(). https://ibb.co/T2s7vm6

Comment: As you see in the picture, this is just a regular generalized FEVD, would be awesome to create such a square matrix with a LASSO and gravitate most of the variables to zero.

Comment: Hi patalalt, unfortunately I'm still having trouble computing the Connectedness Table. This is the table I would like to end up with https://ibb.co/JHd2Qmy. This can be computed by the R package, genFEVD() https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/frequencyConnectedness/versions/0.1.6/topics/genFEVD.

Comment: Haven’t worked with that in the past, but will have a look @Manfretto

Comment: thanks a lot, appreciate it. Working on my master's thesis econometrics :)

Comment: I've added a solution in (**Edit 2**). As I said above, I'm not familiar with GFEVDs and haven't had time to read up on it yet. But provided the function from `frequencyConnectedness` is correct, then so is the custom function above. I'm a bit struck by the fact that `frequencyConnectedness::genFEVD` uses reduced-form rather than orthogonalised IRFs, but let's assume that's correct?

Comment: awesome! Edit 2 seems to give the same results as GenFEVD() yes. The h-step ahead forecast in a square matrix. Appreciate the help! It's a really interesting way to define connectedness.

Comment: No worries, good luck with the thesis! Would you mind accepting my answer since this solves your problem?